When freezing liquids in a glass mason jar, is the regular metal lid air tight, or does a tightly-fit piece of aluminum foil make it air tight?
Some glass freezer containers have a silicon band that comes up against the glass container, to keep air out and avoid freezer burn or odors. With mason jars, there's a metal lid with a reddish band around the edge that creates a seal when canning. Is that regular metal lid and reddish seal sufficient when freezing liquids from room temperature in a glass mason jar?
If not, would it be sufficient tightly pressing aluminum foil to seal the glass jar, then tightening that down with the regular metal mason jar lid and band?
For context, I am asking as I research mason jars as a plastic-free option to store breast milk. I have the freezer space for it but want to make sure the regular freezer-safe jars are suitable for this. The only issue I see is this question of air-tightness.

There might be another issue: freezing liquid in a glass jar might not be a good idea as water expands slightly when it freezes, which could shatter the glass.  It's possible that jars without a shoulder at the top (or not filling the jar to the shoulder) might be less problematic (as the liquid could expand in that direction slightly)

A quick search on glass jars for freezing led me to a blog that also mentioned the shoulders (and they mentioned leaving the caps a little loose, then tighten after freezing): https://abetterwaytothrive.com/freezing-in-glass-no-more-broken-jars/

and another blog that recommends using wide-mouth jars, but also shows a picture of a Ball jar that has a 'for freezing' line embossed into the glass: https://thehomesteadingrd.com/can-you-freeze-mason-jars/  they also recommend stainless steel lids to avoid rust from condensation

The rubber seal of the regular lid should be air-tight. Adding foil under it would make it more prone to leak.
